# EventBus called multiple times in ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-dialog, greenrobot-eventbus

I have a ViewPagerAdapter like this

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    List<MovieCategory> movieCategoryList;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<MovieCategory> movieCategoryList) {
        super(fm);
        this.movieCategoryList = movieCategoryList;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return MoviePagerFragment.start(movieCategoryList, position, "listing");

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieCategoryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return movieCategoryList.get(position).getCategoryTitle();

    }
}
```

This ViewPagerAdapter is calling MoviePagerFragment using this static method in the MoviePagerFragment class

```
public static Fragment start(List<MovieCategory> movieCategoryList, int position, String from) {
    Fragment moviePagerFragment = new MoviePagerFragment();
    Bundle basket = new Bundle();
    basket.putString("from",from);
    basket.putInt("viewpager-position",position);
    basket.putParcelableArrayList("movie_category_list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) movieCategoryList);
    basket.putParcelableArrayList("movie_list", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) movieCategoryList.get(position).getMovies());
    moviePagerFragment.setArguments(basket);
    return moviePagerFragment;
}
```

Now I am registering/unregistering EventBus like this in MoviePagerFragment

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Then I have a method to subscribe to the events dispatched like this

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(final MovieBuyEvent event) {
    final double moviePrice = Double.parseDouble(event.getMoviesItem().getMoviePrice());
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.channel_buy_dialog);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    Button bBuy = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bBuy);
    Button bCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
    final TextView tvPrice = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(event.getMoviesItem().getMoviePicture()).placeholder(R.mipmap.placeholder).into(imageView);
    tvName.setText(event.getMoviesItem().getMovieName());
    tvPrice.setText(event.getMoviesItem().getMovieName());
    dialog.show();
}
```

The MovieBuyEvent is being broadcasted from the ItemClick of an item in RecyclerViewAdapter's ViewHolder class like this

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        position = getAdapterPosition();
        MoviesItem moviesItem = moviesItemList.get(position);
        try {
            MovieBuyEvent movieBuyEvent = new MovieBuyEvent();
                movieBuyEvent.setMoviesItem(moviesItem);
                EventBus.getDefault().post(movieBuyEvent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Now the problem is, every time I swipe a fragment EventBus is registered and unregistered that many times and so

> onMessageEvent(final MovieBuyEvent event)

method is also invoked that many times which is making Dialog appear multiple times. So where should I register/unregister EventBus in a Fragment which is invoked by ViewPagerAdapter?

Comment: How and where are you broadcasting the MovieBuyEvent?

Comment: I am broadcasting the MovieBuyEvent from the RecyclerViewAdapter's ViewHolder onClick listener, please check the question again, I have update the code.

Comment: How many instances of your fragment do you have? It could be called in each instance of you fragment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple fragments that have registered to listen for `MovieBuyEvent` broadcasts they are all going to respond, that stands to reason. If you registered your event listener in the activity or fragment that contains the viewpager that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your register event from `onStart()` to `onCreateView()`. This is because onStart is always [called when the Fragment is visible to the user](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onStart()).

Then try unregistering in `onDestroy()`:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never used setOffscreenPageLimit in your viewpager you should limit to one.
By default viewpager is loading three fragments current one that you see when you just open the parent fragment/activity and two more one after the other. Try to setOffscreenPageLimit to one when you initlize your viewpager. Basically it will load one fragment at a time instead of three each viewpager scroll. When you use the event bus it will get only to one fragment at a time instead of all the fragments that are in use.